# Java, reading the file from input.txt has an issue

Tags: java

I am working on the project. For my purpose, I need to use them that find the median of medians.

At my point, I need to see the read

I also created the input.txt like that below

```
3 7
1 4 5 7 9 11 13
```

Below the snippet, I created the variable for the readpath.

```
// need the variable of filename to read
    private static final String INPUT_FILE_PATH = "input.txt";
```

So, then I appended the code that needs to read the numerical integers in the input.txt in the main function as known below

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        // read the input file
        // TODO need to fix this readpath that gets the bad input
        // ! ASAP
        Path inputPath = Paths.get(INPUT_FILE_PATH);
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        List<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<>(0);
        try {
            fileLines = Files.readAllLines(inputPath, charset);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error reading file: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        int read_line = 0;
        try {
            read_line = Integer.parseInt(fileLines.get(0));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.err.println("bad file input");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("reading... " + read_line);
        // end of reading the filename operation
}
```

As a result, this code suppose to work. I get the output that is bad file input. I do not understand why it gets bad file. By the way, I put all files together in the same directory.

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: `read_line = Integer.parseInt(fileLines.get(0));` parseInt expect _one_ integer. Not a whole bunch of them. Print the actual exception message. It will help you.

Comment: "bad file input" is not the error I would print here. You're not getting "bad file input", you're getting a NumberFormatException because you are trying to convert "3 7" to an Integer - you can't do that because of the whitespace.

Comment: _"The **characters in the string must all be decimal digits**, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value."_ [parseInt​(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: @ThomasMartin there is nothing errors. it only displays the bad file input.

Comment: @Fildor thanks. I will check it out.

Comment: @sleepToken mmm...i did not realize that. I will modify that snippet code in my editor. thanks

Comment: @Carlos split the complete line read by the program into delimiters (whitespace  between two numbers in this case) ; also log/print out the ``ex.getMessage();`` along with the generic message of Bad file input.

Comment: I downvote foremost because the title is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int read_line = 0;
    int read_line2 = 0;
    try {
        String[] words = fileLines.get(0).split("\\s+"); // Split on whitespace.
        read_line = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
        read_line2 = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.err.println("bad file input - not a number; " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

The line contains two numbers, and results in a NumberFormatException.